# Wrong number of touches on Android devices

Tags: android, multi-touch, motionevent

On some `Android` devices e.g. `Samsung S2` I receive an incorrect number of touches. For instance sometimes when I perform 3-4 simultaneously touches `MotionEvent` identifies only 2 of them.
Looks like it's the device-specific issues, but is there a way to handle it?

Comment: I think its about your touch screen's sensitivity. Looks like there is no way to handle it. Have you ever tried any different devices? What are the results?

Comment: I had similar issues, with a galaxy mini (the old one) the touches seem to work perfectly, but when trying another device it would register `ACTION_DOWN` when I was lifting a finger while another one was already touching, I doubt there is anything us programmers can do, you should just assume that it works perfectly (it would be best if your app is not based on this method)

Comment: @oguzhand yes, other devices work quite good, I haven't experienced that issue on others.

Comment: @TomTsagk I use both ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_POINTER_DOWN. I noticed that the issue is reproducible if I touch the screen with 3-4 fingers very quickly or the fingers are located too close to each other.